# Controller or model: who should implement business methods in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I read from here:

http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=287

> the Controller represents the application's business logic. The Model is that component that maintains the state of the entities.

But if I read the MVC original paper it doesn't the same thing in my opinion:
http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/1979/mvc-2/1979-12-MVC.pdf

As I understand the controller is just like a traffic cop, model since it represents knowledge should implements the business methods.

What's your view ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO it's the model that should implement the business methods used by the controller. For me the model is a set of business objects and service methods which represent the operations with those objects. MVC is just a pattern. For example if tomorrow you decide to change the pattern and use something else, go ahead, no problem, but you shouldn't change your business models, they are at the hearth of everything.

Comment: Agreed 1000% that the business logic belongs in the model.  The controller should ideally only serve to facilitate communication between the model (business logic) and the view (display).

Answer (score 3):

In MVC applications that I work on, business logic is encapsulated in a Domain assembly - which is shared across a number of applications. The domain is orchestrated by the controller and I use a dumb "ViewModel" to pass data between the controller and each view.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: what do you mean by "dumb" ?

Comment: "dumb" generally means no business logic.